# Entity Framework and connection string max Timeouts

Tags: c#, connection-string, entityconnection

I'm using a DbContext and want set CommandTimeout = 1 week. What is max timeout value  for 
CommandTimeout?

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this.context).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = ?max?;
```

In connection string I also need set max time out value. What is max Connect Timeout value i can set?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=DBTest;user id=sa;password=p/w; Connect Timeout=?max?; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />    
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7023772/122005) may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value of 0 indicates no limit (an attempt to execute a command will wait indefinitely). So 'indefinitely' is max value.